# Recording controller output

Tags: control, pid

I am a new to the field of control systems.

In real life systems, such as process industry or continuous manufacturing, where large number of feedback control loops are present - is controller output always recorded and preserved in a dataset? If one has to do an offline analysis using the setpoint, controller output, and process variable - using historic data collected at batch level, is this data generally recorded and available? I would assume that process variable and setpoint data would be available, but would like to know if Controller output is also recorded and stored?

Answer (score 1):

Really comes down to the system and how you want to implement it. Sometimes it never records, other times it always records, other times it comes with a debug mode that records for you to analyse when developing and turn off in production systems.

Control data for high frequency processes does blow up quite quickly in size though, so most people aren't constantly recording their 500 Hz+ PID loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Raghav Mishra. This helps!